# How can i change background on webPage twice with js

Tags: javascript, jsdom

the function should change the background to red and to blue with 1 second
between the two operations, but when i run it i find that the first change does not appear on the page

i put the "sleep" function  as i thought the 2 changes happen in the same time

```
   function changeBackGround()
   {
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"; 
   sleep(1000); 
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";

   }


 function sleep(milliseconds) {
   var start = new Date().getTime();
   for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++)
   {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) 
     {
     break;
     }
   }
  }
```

i expect that the page background should first be red and after 1 second it becomes blue

Answer (score 0):

Your homebrewed `sleep` function locks up the event loop in a busy loop. This prevents the browser from repainting the page, so while the DOM has updated, the background isn't reflected in the rendered page.

Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) if you want to run a bit of code after some time.

Answer (score 0):

you can define the function to accept the color as an argument like this:

```
function changeBackGround(color) {
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = color; 
}
```

and you can use `setTimeout` to execute a function after given period in milliseconds

```
window.onload = function() {
  changeBackGround('red');
  setTimeout(function() {
    changeBackGround('blue');
  }, 1000);
}
```